# how to remove duplicate data at array?

Tags: php, arrays, laravel-5

can somebody help me ?

i have variable containing an array from another function :

```
//variable from apriori function
$mightAlsoLike = $this->apriori();
dd($mightAlsoLike);
```

and the variable return like this:

```
[
  [
    "7"
  ],
  [
    "32"
  ],
  [
  "7",
  "32"
  ]
]
```

my probelm is how can u to remove duplicate id at array variable ?
im newb ,very grateful if anyone helps.

sorry for my broken english, thanks.

Comment: please add an example (or more than one) what you need. Do you wish to remove the array's containing only 1 value? or the last ones?

Comment: remove duplicate values , example [['7'],['32],['7','32']] to [['7],['32']] or [['7','32']] , is that possible ? thanks before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
<?php

$data = [[7], [32], [1,2], [2,32]];

foreach($data as $sub) {
    foreach($sub as $val[]);
}
$val = array_unique($val);
var_dump($val);
```